# why don't have blue lines in row 256 and column 256?

Tags: python, scikit-image

Consider the following example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage as nd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io
%matplotlib inline

url_astronaut = ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/master/skimage/data/astronaut.png')
image_gridded = io.imread(url_astronaut)
image_gridded[128:-1:128, :] = [0, 0, 255]
image_gridded[:, 128:-1:128] = [0, 0, 255]

plt.imshow(image_gridded);
```

And the result is

[image]

Having `np.arange(512)[128:-1:128]` is `array([128, 256, 384])`, why don't have blue lines in row 256 and column 256?

This example is from https://github.com/elegant-scipy/notebooks/blob/master/notebooks/ch3.ipynb .

Comment: the result is a grid of lines, and i think there is a line in 256 , 256. please check again

Comment: OK I see the issue, you are missing the middle horizontal and vertical grid line for some reason, would be worth including an image, to show what you're talking about

Comment: Tried it in IPython (removed the `%matplotlib inline`), and it works for me: https://i.imgur.com/9vCcOfN.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code is working fine and the lines are in fact in the image, but they are not shown in the output "preview". If you zoom in to the image, you will see that the blue line appears.

Comment: I zoomed but see nothing

Comment: At the end of your code add the following line:

io.imsave("astronaut_lines.png", image_gridded)

Adjust the save filename/path if desired. Now open the image with an external viewer. See the lines now?

Comment: Thanks, I see the lines, now. Another way is set the size of the figure bigger, this way help seeing the lines right in jupyter notebook.